# Remove elements from dict in for loop

Tags: python

How can I delete all elements in a dictionary after a modified one?
If the second one is changed, then we delete everything that is behind it or, if the first one is changed, then we delete everything after it and so on.

```
d = {'first': 'one', 'second': 'two', 'third': 'three'}
k = 'second'

for key in d:
    if k in key:
        d[key] = 'new value'
        # delete third
```

Comment: Dicts are not sorted, so this is not possible unless you convert it to a list and sort it yourself.

Comment: @MichaelBianconi - beginning Python v3.7 (3,6) insertion order is maintained so this is definitely *doable*.

Comment: Delete **everything** after it ? If there are twenty items and the third is modified the delete items 4-20?

Comment: What exactly does "after" mean here? It implies some sort of ordering of the keys, but the question does not make it clear what that is. It could be ascending alphabetical order, or insertion order (if python >= 3.7 is being used), or just undefined order (if python < 3.6 is being used).

Comment: You would need to make a new dictionary filtering out the unwanted items. Attempting to modify the original -- `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code. it makes the dict items into a list and creates a new dict from the remaining items:

```
d = {'first': 'one', 'second': 'two', 'third': 'three'}
k = 'second'
d[k] = 'NewValue'
d = dict(list(d.items())[:list(d.keys()).index(k)+1])
print(d)
```

Out:

```
{'first': 'one', 'second': 'NewValue'}
```

Out of curiosity I timed it against @Daniel's answer those are my timeit code and result:

```
import timeit, functools

def test_1(d,k):
    d = dict(list(d.items())[:list(d.keys()).index(k)+1])
    d[k] = 'new vlaue'
    return d

def test_2(d, k):
    new_d = {}
    for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
        if key == k:
            new_d[key] = 'new value'
            break
        new_d[key] = value
    return new_d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    keys = [x for x in range(100000)]
    values = [x for x in range(100000)]

    d = dict(zip(keys, values))
    k = 9999
    a = timeit.timeit(functools.partial(test_1, d, k), number = 1000)
    b = timeit.timeit(functools.partial(test_2, d, k), number = 1000)
    print(a, b)
```

Output:

```
5.107241655999815 6.745305094000059
```

If you change the `sorted(...)` into `list(...)` in Daniels answer it is the other way around:

```
5.046288972999946 4.211456709999993
```

It is a constant offset, probably due to creating the list out of the dict twice instead of once. So @Daniels answer is both faster and less memory expensive

Comment: I will have the words in the keys. Like "category", "section" and so on. Thank you for your research!

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, I just let it run with `[str(x) for x in range(100000)` and `k=str(9999)` and the result is the same

Answer (score 2):

Instead of deleting elements, just create a new dictionary.
Since dictionaries are not ordered, you should sort the items in some way.

```
d = {'first': 'one', 'second': 'two', 'third': 'three'}
k = 'second'

new_d = {}
for key, value in sorted(d.items()):
    if key == k:
        new_d[key] = 'new value'
        break
    new_d[key] = value
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what you need!

Comment: Using `sorted` only works here because `'first'`, `'second'` and `'third'` are in alphabetical order by coincidence. Chances are, this is a toy example for Stack Overflow and the real keys are different.

Comment: Yes you are right. But this is my mistake in indicating the question.

Answer (score 0):

you can delete rest of dict by keys. like below:

```
d = {'first': 'one', 'second': 'two', 'third': 'three'}
k = 'first' #for modify

keys = ['second', 'third'] #rest of dict to delete

list(map(d.pop, keys))
```

it will return `{'first':'modified_value'}`

Comment: Using `list(map(...))` to achieve side-effects is not a good idea. Why not just write `for k in keys: d.pop(k)`?

Comment: Thanks. This works well, but Daniel answered earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using normal dictionary if you're trying to keep them in an order, at least if you're below py3.7 of course.

Please use if you're below 3.7.

We are creating a new dictionary in the below code and removing the old one, you can even put this inside a function and use it.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

d =OrderedDict([('first','one'), ('second', 'two'), ('third', 'three')])
k = 'second'

output_dict = OrderedDict()
for key,value in d.items():
    if k in key:
        output_dict[key] = value
        break
    else:
        output_dict[key] = value
del d
print(output_dict)
```